# How to store object from inherited class when I am not supposed to have containers for that class

Tags: c++, oop

I am creating a class that inherits another class and have constructor which is required to have a parameter - object of the base class -

My question is what do I do with that object how do I store it so I can access its attributes?

I am not supposed to create other attributes/containers like `list<Baseclass> name`

```
class TelephoneSub // Base class
{
private:
    string ts_name;
    string ts_country_code;
    double ts_tariff_plan;
    int ts_minutes_call; 
public:
TelephoneSub(const TelephoneSub &p) 
    {
        this->ts_name = p.ts_name;
        this->ts_country_code = p.ts_country_code;
        this->ts_tariff_plan = p.ts_tariff_plan;
        this->ts_minutes_call = p.ts_minutes_call;
    }
```

Derived class

```
class TelephoneSubData : public TelephoneSub
{
private:
    string tsd_phone_number;
    vector<TelephoneSubData>tsd_contacts;
    list<TelephoneSubData>tsd_called_numbers;
public:
    // 2.1
    TelephoneSubData() {}
    // 2.2
    TelephoneSubData(const string number,const TelephoneSub &sub)
    {
        this->tsd_phone_number = number;
        TelephoneSub::TelephoneSub(sub);
    }

double average_sum()const
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (auto x : tsd_called_numbers)
        {
            i++;
            sum += x.get_ts_tariff_plan();
        }
        return sum / i;
    }
```

Comment: I think you might want to rethink this design, I wouldn't expect a data class to be a child and certainly wouldn't expect vectors/lists of a class to members of it.

Comment: For me it's completely unclear what you want to achieve. Do you need to access any additional attributes from `TelephoneSub``in your derived class? Consider using virtual functions then.

Comment: I've got functions to write in the TelephoneSubData class and they require me to have access to the attributes with values from the object in the copy constructor in the TelephoneSubData class - how do i access the values of that object ? Cause right now they go into some random places in the memory as i have not assigned them to a specific object like this